# How do i replace an expression with metacharacters using preg_replace in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've tried in different ways, replacing a excerpt of text with metacharacters with another text with metacharacters in PHP. I know, it seems very simple but i've tried many times but didn't get it.

pattern: `$Sel = 'anyvalues';`

replacement: `$Sel = 'one other';`

subject: `<?php $Sel = 'anyvalues';`

I deeply tried using addslashes() and preg_quote() methods in different orders but it doesn't work. I need it to be as represented instead of looking for any workarounds.

Each one of these values lie in different files, i.e.,  the ***pattern*** lies in one file, ***replacement*** in another one, and ***subject*** in another as well.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example (or at least a small excerpt) of the original and replacement texts?

Comment: It's more like: 
`$pattern = file_get_contents(file with $Sel = 'anyvalues'; value);


$replacement =  file_get_contents(file with $Sel =  'one other' value);


$subject = file_get_contents(file with <?php$Sel = 'anyvalues'; value );


$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wrapped your pattern in [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)?

```
$pattern = '$Sel = "anyvalues_containing_delimiter_/";';
$replacement = '$Sel = "one other";';
$subject = '<?php $Sel = "anyvalues_containing_delimiter_/";';

echo preg_replace(sprintf('/%s/', preg_quote($pattern, '/')), $replacement, $subject);
```

The contents of pattern are the only ones that need escaping, hence the `preg_quote` call. Second argument is the delimiter in which the pattern is wrapped (what `sprintf` does here), so any occurences within the pattern content can also be escaped before they are applied.

Edit: I've modified the snippet to cover for occurences of the delimiter within file contents.

Second edit: moved code from linked snippet into the answer itself.

Comment: Yes, i've tried also delimiting all arguments, more like file_get_contents('/'.$subject.'/'), but it also didn't work.

Comment: Only the pattern should be delimited. Nevertheless, if it works for the example, but doesn't work for your actual files, then you really need to provide a better sample of the content you're trying this on.

Comment: One more thing crossed my mind; I've edited my answer, can you try again?

Comment: sorry, actually i did it just to illustratre, i did it similar to - preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/', $replacement, $subject);, where each argument pointed to file content retrieved with file_get_contents() method, and tried different approaches, with many other methods.

Comment: In that case, I can't help you further unless you supply some actual files to try on.

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: It's actually what i'm looking for, but let just implement it and try, and let you know  if it worked. Anyway many thanks for the effort in advance.

Comment: @Toto I've replaced the link with the actual code. Thanks for the tip, it completely escaped my attention.

Comment: @El_Vanja, it's definitely what i'm looking for but it doesn't work where i want, but works as expected here. Anyway, thank You very much. I'll still trying to make it work.